# Was Governor Solá expelled from Mexico?

Tags: spain, colonial-america, mexico, spanish-empire, decolonization

[Pablo Vicente de Solá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablo_Vicente_de_Sol%C3%A1) was a Spanish military officer who served resisting the Hidalgo Revolt and then as the last Spanish governor of Alta California. [Nuttall: *The Gobernantes of Spanish Upper California: A Profile*]. He ended his Mexican political career by serving on the Committee for the Development of California [Reynolds: *Principal Actions of the California Junta De Fomento 1825-1827*]. He was thought to have  died in 1826 [Johnson: *Pablo Vicente de Solá: Transitional Governor of Alta California*] but in Reynolds, his signature appeared on a Junta document from 1827.

Between 1827 and 1834 the Mexican government passed several laws mandating that Spaniards (*gachupines*) leave the country. It succeeded in expelling at least three quarters of the Mexicans of Spanish birth, particularly the military men and bureaucrats [Sims: *The Expulsion of Mexico's Spaniards, 1821-1836*].

Was Solá among those expelled?